# How to add extended calendar from JIL file

Tags: autosys

I am trying to add an extended_calendar in my autosys. Can i add the same using a jil file?

I tried using autocal_asc -I test.txt but that is giving me Calendar Create Access Denied!(same case with interactive cmd console using autocal_asc)

This is my sample contents of txt file

```
    extended_calendar:test  
    description:Runs on 1st day of the month
    workday: mo,tu,we,th,fr
    non_workday:
    holiday:
    holcal:
    cyccal:
    adjust: 0
    condition: MNTHD#1
```

Comment: The JIL is fine... error "Calendar Create Access Denied!" indicates you dont have the edit    permission... mostly this would be the middleware team depending on the DEV / PROD env. There are 3 kinds of permission 1. Read 2. Execute 3. Edit... You might me missing the 3 one

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But is there a way to add an extended calendar without using autocal_asc. I want to put the cal  in a jil file ina similar way we have insert_job: 
 or delete_job kind of job definitions.

Comment: If you are saying that you can insert / delete jobs, then i will assume that you have full edit permissions. Your extended_calendar JIL looks fine to me, and should be processed just like the way insert_job / delete_job JIL file works. Have you tried it ?

Comment: buddy, the error explicitly says "Calendar Create Access Denied!" ... must be some policy set by admin to restrict creation of Calendar. Check with the middleware / admin / scheduling team. Until you have the right permission, you would not be able to do it either from the GUI or CLI.